# Bought Samsung Galaxy II in China, need to change alerts, etc. to English

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, languages

I just bought my phone here in China and have changed the language settings to English.  I get all my alerts, error messages, ets. in Chinese characters.  Wish I could read them, but since I can't, how do I make my phone communicate to me in English?  I am a total Android newbie having dumped my iPhone and it's lackluster battery for this phone.  As soon as I tweak it a bit, I'll be thrilled.
By the way, pretend I am in kindergarten when explaining what to do, otherwise I'll have to ask my son to help and I really don't want to give him more tech power over me than he already has.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If you've changed the language settings to English and still see Chinese characters in the stock apps, i'd be worried about the authenticity of the phone...

Answer (score 3):

You could get a [US/UK Firmware from samfirmwarec.com](http://www.samfirmware.com/WEBPROTECT-i9100.htm) and flash it with [heimdall](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=755265) / [odin](http://droidangel.blogspot.com/2011/05/odin-multi-downloader-flasher-program.html). But you will lose your warranty and I can not guarantee that it will work (**it could even leave your phone in an unusable state**).
Flashing can be done with three easy steps:

1. get your phone in download mode
2. connect it with usb
3. configure heimdall/odin and start the process

There are some other things that you need to be aware off, but everything is documented in the links I included. Maybe you son will also help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you once try Menu-> Settings -> Language & Keyboard.
The first entry is "Select language".
English is third in the list in my phone.

Answer (score -1):

You can change to English: Go to Settings , then select language.

I bought mine in Beijing and I only use English.